# Visual Studio adds columns to DataGridView after running program

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008, datagridview

I have a datagridview that is linked to a three columns in the database, and it's only displaying them (no editing). When I run the program in debug, and exit, when I return to the form in Visual Studio, it has my three columns, plus all the columns in the table it's linked to. If I don't remove these, the next time I run the program, they show up on the form. If I remove them, I have to do it every time I run the program.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: How is it linked to the database? Are you using a strongly-typed dataset and a BindingSource, or some other method?

Comment: It is being bound with a strongly typed dataset and binding source

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this](http://74.125.77.132/search?q=cache:JQGWmnOG24YJ:social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdesigner/thread/39e239fa-ea7e-4e72-a12b-07948b066b5a/+visual+studio+after+running+program+datagridview&hl=en&ct=clnk&cd=3&gl=us&client=firefox-a) there is a bug in Visual Studio that requires you to set the binding source to none/null before changing it (It seems to have been around since 2005). I removed all the columns, set binding source to none, then reset the binding source to what I wanted and edited the columns. It is working now.

Comment: Looks like you've found the answer and thanks for sharing the link.

Comment: I think the link might be trying to point to here (same thread ID):  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/39e239fa-ea7e-4e72-a12b-07948b066b5a/columns-in-datagridview-reorder-themselves-after-build

Answer (score 4):

Is `AutoGenerateColumns` set to `True` ?

You should set it to `False` if you want to prevent the DGV from creating columns (in addition to those you created manually) from the datasource.

Edit: To clarify, this admittedly weird behaviour could result if the property is not  set to False in design mode itself. I'm thinking of the corner case in which you set it to `False` at runtime. I would also take a look at the designer file (you might have to click the "show all files" option to view it) and see what it contains pertaining to the DGV. Might be a problem there.

Alternatively, have you tried deleting the control itself and creating a new DGV with the same bindings?

Comment: AutoGeneratedColumns is set to false.

Comment: The designer file sets the AutoGeneratedColumns to false, and only shows the columns I manually added. Not the ones that get added after running the program.

Answer (score 3):

After lots of digging around, [this solution](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdesigner/thread/d8b758b9-a916-43c4-8e41-c901112d38d5/#2b2d5f49-5e0f-4d97-84c9-51f9169bcef3) finally solved it for me:

> It looks like the compiler is corrupting the .resx file (which
>   contains the form's layout information, including the column
>   settings), which means next time you load the designer it recreates
>   all the columns from the datasource.
>
> The fix appears to be as follows:
>
> > Do a "show all files" and then view the .resx file associated with the
> >     form and change the columns that are giving you the aberrant
> >     behavior... look for the column name followed by ".UserAddedColumn"
> >     Entry, and set it to False.  In my case I actually went so far as to
> >     altogether delete the entries that say "[columnName].UserAddedColumn".